# Minimum distance between arcs of $\frac{x^2}{x-5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The graph of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x-5}$ forms two arcs separated by a vertical asymptote at x=5. I would like to know the minimum distance between the two arcs. I don’t believe that the minimum distance is just length of the segment which spans between the maximum of the arc for $x<5$ and the arc for $x>5$.

Comment: it is a hyperbola. The shortest distance is along oe of the symmetry axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That curve is a hyperbola of equation

$$x^2-xy+5y=0.$$

Its center is obtained by solving

$$\begin{cases}2x-y=0,\\-x+5=0,\end{cases}$$

which gives $(5,10)$. Hence the centered equation

$$x^2-xy+25.$$

We can rotate the coordinates by

$$(u\cos t+v\sin t)^2-(u\cos t+v\sin t)(v\cos t-u \sin t)+25=0$$ and we cancel the product $uv$ with

$$2\cos t\sin t-\cos^2t+\sin^2t=\sin2t-\cos2t=0$$ or $$t=\frac\pi8.$$

Then the equation reduces to

$$\sin t(\sin t-\cos t)v^2+\cos t(\sin t+\cos t)u^2+25=0$$

and the intersections with the axis, which are the two points that will tell you the searched distances, are given by

$$v^2=-\frac{25}{\sin t(\sin t-\cos t)}=\frac{50}{\sqrt2-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Define $g(x):=\dfrac{(x+5)^2}{x}-10=\dfrac{x^2+25}{x}=f(x+5)-10$.

$g(x)$ is an odd function, so to find the minimum distance between the arcs of $f(x)$, we can minimize the distance between $g(x)$ and the origin.  Can you take it from here?

Final answer:

> About $23.528$ units.

Comment: I don’t think that is correct, as the distance between the points at x=0 and x=10 can be computed to be about 22.36.

Comment: The idea should be correct. I must have made a computational error.